# Git: Need to list latest 5 branches in git

Tags: git

I am trying to get latest 5 branches using git. I have tried `git branch -r --sort=-committerdate` but it gets me all branches sorted by committerdate. Is there any way to get latest 5 one?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git branch -r --sort=-committerdate | head -5` will give you the latest five branches.

Comment: Just to add a little extra data (date, author name, ref) and formatting, 
`git branch -r --sort=-committerdate --format='%(committerdate:short) %(authorname) %(refname:short)' | head -5`